# Electric generator fuel consumption while load is increased

Tags: power-supply, ac, power-electronics, generator, power-generation

I am working on a gas plant that produces its own energy with an electogren group that operates with LPG as fuel.

I noticed that this plant is oversized. It has a capacity of 150 kVA but the plant rarely demands more than 26 kW.

The electrogen group has fabric sensors that display the power factor on a screen. This value fluctuates between 0.6 and 0.9 depending if some sinchronic pumps are working or not.

I think this means that the generator is capable of producing 150*PowerFactor power in that instant. I got the idea of selling the extra energy but I have the following doubt. Does the electrogen group generate this 150*PowerFactor power output or just the 26 kW demanded by the plan? If it is generating that power output where does the extra power go?

The generator has an automatic voltage regulator (AVR) system that I read works by letting more current pass to the stator of the generator which also will generate the strength of the magnetic field oposed to the movement of the shaft. Is this the way the ouput is regulated?

Where is all the combustion engine mechanical powergoing?

I understanded that if the engine does not has any transmision coupledd, as is my case, it will behave as the power-torque-rpm curves. The engine is a GM Vortec v8 5.7 L engine. The generator works at 1800 RPM. It is a 4 pole generator 60 Hz, 220 V and is a DSE 7420 genset.

Comment: That's not what power factor is.

Comment: why? i tried to say: if the generator has a aparent power of 150 KVA, the real power output is powerFactor*aparentpower? isn't that correct?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean the generator is capable of producing any more or less power than its rating. The generator is *rated* for 150 kVA, but that doesn't mean it's constantly generating 150 kVA of apparent power.

Comment: In an ideal world, no load on the generator and engine would consume zero fuel.  But there are always losses and inefficiencies at every step, so perhaps it would consume 1L/hr unloaded.  The more you load that generator, up to it's rating, the more fuel/hr will be consumed (energy.)  More load also means more wear-and-tear, so more maintenance.

Comment: i know it cant produce 150 kVA that's why I said that the control module has a sense of second to second of the power factor that oscilates between 0.6 and 0.9 so does this value multiply for 150 isn't the real power outpu?

Comment: No. The power factor multiplied by the *current apparent power output* is the current real power output. It's not related to the rated power at all.

Comment: If the plant's taking 26kW, the generator is generating 26/PF kVA. (And if you sell excess power, you'll consume more gas and add wear to the plant, increasing costs)

Comment: can i say the analogy: when there is no load the engine is working part time and the other times is rotating freely without resistance or less resistance to rotate (inertia). I mean if the current that the Load  let pass to the generator increase, the magnetic field force that opose rotation will also increase, but this increase in force is proportional to the consumption in a linear manner or more in a logaritmic one?.

Answer (score 1):

You must do an energy balance.

If the generator consumes x number of liters per second, you can get the power. LPG has an energy per volume of (25.68 MJ / L).  So the input is:

InputPower = ( (25680 [KJ/L] * x [L/s] )  ;where x is LPG volume per second

So the output power is:

OutputPower = n * InputPower  ;where n is the generator efficiency.

So, if there is not nonlinear loads.

n* InputPower = V * I * cos (\phi)

> And if it is generating that power output where does that excedent is
> going?

From an energy point of view:
The generator have a regulator at the input in order to generate a fixed signal in voltage and frequency. In this way, the amount of gas it will consume will depend on the load. If you don't have a regulator, the voltage and frequency value of the generator will vary.

From a useful energy point of view. I mean, when the power factor is less than 1.The farther the power factor is from 1, the more energy will be dissipated into heat in the conductors.

Comment: But this is still something oversized right? and does the power factor is related to the aparent power of 150 or to the (power demanded)/PowerFactor as @rdtsc said? how can i determine the total amount of energy that i could be able to produce and sell?

Comment: You have to check the specs of the generator. What is its nominal power. That is the maximum power it can deliver in a steady state. If it's 150 KVA, thats the nominal apparent power.  S_toSell = 150 KV - S_powerPlant and the power plant consumption: S_powerPlant = sqrt( ( V.I cos(phi) ) ^2 + ( VI sin (\phi) )^2 ) .  Where V * I Sin (phi) is the reactive power

Answer (score 0):

The motor will increase its output (use more fuel) according to the load on the generator.  This might be a simple mechanical speed governor like a lawn mower engine or an electronic speed controller.

Simply, as the regulator increases the draw from the generator, the motor will slow down and the motor speed control (mechanical or electronic) will then add fuel to maintain rpm.

Now, if you want to sell power to the grid, you will need a new regulator that connects to the grid and increases output so that the grid is fed.  This is EE 101 on power production - house diagrams, etc.  Whether it is economical to do so would be based on the new capital cost to make it happen, price you can sell to the grid, your cost of LPG, and associated wear and tear on components.  This might be profitable only during peak hours, which would lead to wanting to integrate a real-time electricity pricing module to determine when to turn on power to the grid.